# Можете сказать почему когда я пишу слово после бота он всегда пишет что оно неправильное

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Я хочу научиться писать код на python и сейчас не сильно в нем разбираясь я пишу своего бота/игру в слова для телеграмма. Но я столкнулся с одной ошибкой. В коде я сделал чтобы бот проверял последнюю букву своего слова и первую букву слова игрока. Я думал что этот код сработает и он сработал но не так как надо. После того как бот написал слово и когда написал слово игрок бот пишет что буквы не совпадают, но на самом деле первые буквы совпадали. Я хочу чтобы кто то более знающий подсказал что я не так сделал и как это исправить. Так же заранее прошу прощения если совершил глупую ошибку и прошу прощения если как то не правильно опубликовал этот вопрос
Вот и сам код:

```
import telebot
import random
import mywords

word_list = mywords.slova

bot = telebot.TeleBot('мой апи')

used_words = {}

game_active = False

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    global game_active
    game_active = True
    bot.reply_to(message, "Добро пожаловать в игру слов! Пожалуйста, введите первое слово:")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['stop'])
def stop(message):
    global game_active
    game_active = False
    used_words.clear()
    bot.reply_to(message, "Игра остановлена. Вы можете начать новую игру с помощью команды /start.")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def play_game(message):
    global game_active

    if not game_active:
        bot.reply_to(message, "Нет активной игры. Начните новую игру с помощью команды /start.")
        return
  
    if message.text.lower() in used_words:
        bot.reply_to(message, "Извините, это слово уже было использовано.")
        return

    if not used_words:
        used_words[message.text.lower()] = True
        last_letter = message.text[-1].lower()
        if last_letter in ['ь', 'ъ', 'ы']:
            last_letter = message.text[-2].lower()
        available_words = [word for word in word_list if word.startswith(last_letter)]
        if available_words:
            next_word = random.choice(available_words)
            used_words[next_word.lower()] = True
            bot.reply_to(message, f"Следующее слово: {next_word}")
        else:
            bot.reply_to(message, "Извините, я не могу найти слово, начинающееся с этой буквы.")
        return
    
    last_bot_word = list(used_words.keys())[-1]
    last_bot_letter = last_bot_word[-1].lower()
 
    first_user_letter = message.text[0].lower()

    if last_bot_letter != first_user_letter:
        game_active = False
        bot.reply_to(message,"Вы проиграли, ваше слово должно начинаться на последнюю букву моего слова")
        return
    
    available_words = [word for word in word_list if word.startswith(first_user_letter)]

    if available_words:
        
        next_word = random.choice(available_words)
        bot.reply_to(message, f"Следующее слово: {next_word}")
        used_words[message.text.lower()] = True
        used_words[next_word.lower()] = True
    else:
        bot.reply_to(message, "Извините, я не могу найти слово, начинающееся с этой буквы.")
 
    if len(used_words) == len(word_list) * 2:
        bot.reply_to(message, "Игра окончена! Все слова были использованы.")
        used_words.clear()
        game_active = False

bot.polling()
```